Sending camera image bytes through grpc to Python
I am building a flutter app that will be sending a video stream to a server through grpc. The server will receive the stream as bytes.
The server will be using Python, and I want to decode the input in a way to use it in CV model.
How can I send it in dart properly?
Future<void> streamVideo(CameraImage image) async {
    try {
      var bytes1 = image.planes[0].bytes;
      var stream = Stream.fromIterable([
        VideoFrame()
          ..data = bytes1
          ..width = image.width
          ..height = image.height
          ..format = 1
      ]);
      var response = await stub.streamVideo(stream);
      print('Streaming status: ${response.success}, Message: ${response.message}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Caught error: $e');
    }
  }

  // Method to cleanly shut down the client
  void shutdown() async {
    await channel.shutdown();
  }
}


See the gRPC documentation for a Quick start for Dart. This should help you get further along with a solution.
